# how to grep lines according to 6th field contents

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I would like to know how to filter lines according to the mem usage: I would like to be able to find only the PIDs that (RES mem usage) exceed 5GB

Explicitly, I have the following lines

```
20697 user    20   0  357m  24m  19m S 19.0  0.1 887:15.00 pulseaudio
13017 user    20   0 8381m 3.7g  35m S 127.7  7.9 803:11.96 MATLAB
12654 user    20   0 11.2g 6.1g  10m S 104.8 13.0 784:41.07 MATLAB
3088 user    20   0 17.4g  12g  11m S 101.0 26.3   2043:48 MATLAB
12548 user    20   0 8797m 3.5g  13m S 101.0  7.4 802:21.00 MATLAB
12785 user    20   0 8543m 3.6g  35m S 101.0  7.6 804:36.81 MATLAB
12909 user    20   0 12.1g 5.5g  28m S 99.1 11.8 796:01.45 MATLAB
13154 user    20   0 10.1g 5.6g  10m S 99.1 11.8 797:07.14 MATLAB
```

and I'd like to grep only the lines where the 6th field is larger than 5 GB

EDIT: Note that sorting is not important. Just selecting the lines that exceed the threshold is important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '$6~/g/ && ($6+0)>5' file
12654 user    20   0 11.2g 6.1g  10m S 104.8 13.0 784:41.07 MATLAB
3088 user    20   0 17.4g  12g  11m S 101.0 26.3   2043:48 MATLAB
12909 user    20   0 12.1g 5.5g  28m S 99.1 11.8 796:01.45 MATLAB
13154 user    20   0 10.1g 5.6g  10m S 99.1 11.8 797:07.14 MATLAB
```

Comment: Thanks. Short and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Using `gawk`:

```
$ cat n.txt
20697 user    20   0  357m  24m  19m S 19.0  0.1 887:15.00 pulseaudio
13017 user    20   0 8381m 3.7g  35m S 127.7  7.9 803:11.96 MATLAB
12654 user    20   0 11.2g 6.1g  10m S 104.8 13.0 784:41.07 MATLAB
3088 user    20   0 17.4g  12g  11m S 101.0 26.3   2043:48 MATLAB
12548 user    20   0 8797m 3.5g  13m S 101.0  7.4 802:21.00 MATLAB
12785 user    20   0 8543m 3.6g  35m S 101.0  7.6 804:36.81 MATLAB
12909 user    20   0 12.1g 5.5g  28m S 99.1 11.8 796:01.45 MATLAB
13154 user    20   0 10.1g 5.6g  10m S 99.1 11.8 797:07.14 MATLAB

$ gawk '
BEGIN{
    k=1024;
    m["k"]=k;
    m["m"]=k*k;
    m["g"]=k*k*k;
}
{
    patsplit($6, a, "([0-9.]*)|([kmg])");
    value=a[1]*m[a[2]];
    if (value>5*k*k*k) print;
}' n.txt 

12654 user    20   0 11.2g 6.1g  10m S 104.8 13.0 784:41.07 MATLAB
3088 user    20   0 17.4g  12g  11m S 101.0 26.3   2043:48 MATLAB
12909 user    20   0 12g 5.5g  28m S 99.1 11.8 796:01.45 MATLAB
13154 user    20   0 10.1g 5.6g  10m S 99.1 11.8 797:07.14 MATLAB
```

A more optimized (& less generic) version:

```
$ awk '$6 ~ /^[0-9.]*g$/{if((0 + $6)>5) print}' n.txt
```

Comment: Why bother with the conversions when it already converts the size in top.You can just search for g. If it says m at the end then its less than a gig so your conversion is a waste of cpu.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using awk

```
$ cat n.txt
20697 user    20   0  357m  24m  19m S 19.0  0.1 887:15.00 pulseaudio
13017 user    20   0 8381m 3.7g  35m S 127.7  7.9 803:11.96 MATLAB
12654 user    20   0 11.2g 6.1g  10m S 104.8 13.0 784:41.07 MATLAB
3088 user    20   0 17.4g  12g  11m S 101.0 26.3   2043:48 MATLAB
12548 user    20   0 8797m 3.5g  13m S 101.0  7.4 802:21.00 MATLAB
12785 user    20   0 8543m 3.6g  35m S 101.0  7.6 804:36.81 MATLAB
12909 user    20   0 12.1g 5.5g  28m S 99.1 11.8 796:01.45 MATLAB
13154 user    20   0 10.1g 5.6g  10m S 99.1 11.8 797:07.14 MATLAB

$ awk '{if($6>=5) {print}}' n.txt
12654 user    20   0 11.2g 6.1g  10m S 104.8 13.0 784:41.07 MATLAB
12909 user    20   0 12.1g 5.5g  28m S 99.1 11.8 796:01.45 MATLAB
13154 user    20   0 10.1g 5.6g  10m S 99.1 11.8 797:07.14 MATLAB
```

Comment: `3088 user    20   0 17.4g  12g  11m S 101.0 26.3   2043:48 MATLAB` should get printed too.

Comment: Almost, it needs to first select that the 6th field terminates with a 'g' and then make sure its value is above 5

Answer (score 0):

```
YourStream | grep -E -e '^([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]{1,}){5}[[:space:]]*([1-9][0-9]|[5-9])(.[0-9]*){0,1}g'
```

- using your stream input and grep.
- for ordering or other action prefer a awk

Comment: i test here (RH EL) and work fine. Any error or it grep all /nothing) ?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use ordering options from the command line, but you can use a workaround to accomplish this.

- Start top (normal mode),
- set order (To order by memory: O n ),
- write config file (W),
- quit top